# calling a java method from a ruby class

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

Here am trying to call a java method inside the  ruby function.

While calling a java function inside a  ruby class.
am getting

```
Atest.rb:9: dynamic constant assignment
     Obj = Java::sikuliAutomation.new
```

my ruby code

```
require 'java'
require 'C:/X/test.jar'

class Main
  def run   
     Obj = Java::sikuliAutomation.new
     Obj.automation
       end
end
app = Main.new
app.run
```

test.jar conatins the method automation

Comment: Except the mentioned warning, what is your problem ? What is the purpose of using constant `Obj` here `Obj = Java::sikuliAutomation.new`, instead of simple local var sa `obj`. ?

Comment: yes obj is correct not Obj. i wanto call a java method inside the run method

Comment: Well, if you change `Obj` to `obj` you still get that warning or what is the problem?

Comment: am getting class not founf exception

Comment: this is a bit poorly asked - you should specify how your test.jar looks - what Java class (under what package) are you trying to call.

comments already answered your original question the failure is due assigning a constant `Obj = Java::sikuliAutomation.new` ... make sure you update the question with the new details/error, thx!